# Unable to login to ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am new to this.
I was playing around ssh. Unknowingly  cleared authorized_keys  present inside /.ssh and saved it. Now my putty session got expired and i am unable to login with the my ppk key .

Any way i can login via putty.

Answer (score 2):

You can regain access to the instance via the following steps:

- **Stop** the instance
- Detach the **boot volume** (remember what it was called, eg `/dev/sda1`)
- Attach the volume to **another EC2 instance** (that you *can* connect to)
- Recreate the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with your public key)
- **Detach** the volume
- **Reattach** the volume to the original instance (with the same device identifier)
- **Start** the instance again
- **SSH** into the instance

Basically, you're putting back the file that was lost.

Comment: Very nice solution to keep exactly the same instance, I assumed OP wasn't very experienced with EC2 so tried to provide as simple as possible solution. Maybe a note worth adding is that this will not work on instance-store backed EC2 instances, only EBS.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to SSH anymore if you cleared your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

If you have data stored on the instance that you do not want to loose, you can snapshot EC2 instance (right click on your existing instance in EC2 console and create image) and then launch a new EC2 instance from created snapshot by providing your key pair. When the new EC2 instance boots it will insert your key pair into `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and you will be able to SSH to it.